# Returnig info of the inserted object in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

Can I get more info of the object I inserted in the databse?

I´m working with node/express and bookshelf. My table has id, name, timestamp. I only need to pass name, the other gets generated internally. So with my code I only get id and name when inserted. Is there a way to get the timestamps created?

```
    const newJob = new Jobs({
        name: req.body.name,
    });

    job.save().then((result) => {   
        return res.json({job: result.fields()});
    })

const Jobs = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tableJobs',
    fields: function() {
         return {
           id: this.get('id'),
           name: this.get('name'),
           timestamp: this.get('timestamp')
         };
     }
  });
```

I get

```
   {
     "job": {
        "id": 2,
         "name": " 100 casos ludik",
       }
  }
```

but want

```
 {
     "job": {
        "id": 2,
         "name": " 100 casos ludik",
         "timestamp": "2018-12-18T15:39:34.000Z"
       }
  }
```

Comment: why dont you query the new object back (with returned id) and get all info you need. This way you do two operations 1 insert, 1 retreive based on created id

Comment: I could but I wanted to know if it was possible and avoid another request

Comment: Without seeing much of your code I would assume that 'this.get' is what you GET from the http request. So it's values that you put into (rather than get out of) the database. Since you don't put a timestamp into the db you're likely going to have to either generate a timestamp that you insert or query the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known feature request: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/1665

Currently you'll have to fetch the object after saving it to see all the fields that are set on the database:

```
job.save().then(() => {
  return job.fetch()   
}).then((result) => {
  return res.json({job: result.fields()});
})
```